# Omitted `Return` in Kotlin need extra code. How to fix that?

Tags: kotlin

When I code an Rx Observable in Java (7), it is as below

```
private Observable observable = Observable.just("http://myurl.com/")
        .map(new Function<String, Person>() {
            @Override
            public Person apply(String url) throws Exception {

                Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
                Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
                Response response = call.execute();

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                    if (responseBody != null) {
                        return Person.parseFrom(responseBody.byteStream());
                    }
                }

                return null;
        }
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

When I convert it to Kotlin, it is as below

```
private val observable = Observable.just("http://myurl.com/")
        .map{
            val request = Request.Builder().url(it).build()
            val call = okHttpClient.newCall(request)
            val response = call.execute()

            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val responseBody = response.body()
                if (responseBody != null) {
                    Person.parseFrom(responseBody.byteStream())
                } else {
                    null
                }
            } else {
                null
            }
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

In the Kotlin version, you might notice I have two `null`s. But in Java, I could avoid doing that, as I could have a return statement in the Map function. How could I achieve that in Kotlin as well without duplicating the `null`?

Comment: Look at the conversion of your code https://pastebin.com/AcYKGHRH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [qualified return](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels):

```
if (response.isSuccessful) {
    val responseBody = response.body()
    if (responseBody != null)
        return@map Person.parseFrom(responseBody.byteStream())
}
return@map null
```

Comment: Vote up my question if you think that will help others in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter

```
val body = response.body
if (response.isSuccessful && body != null) {
       Person.parseFrom(body.byteStream())
} else null
```

Comment: The response.body once accessed, is no longer accessible. Hence it has to be stored in a variable.

Comment: @Elye How about now?

Comment: That's possible. But we don't want to waste time accessing and storing the body (an expensive process) if it is not successful.